# Timeouts and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to generate 4 circles when the page loads. However, even though the function is called 4 times, I'm only seeing one. I'm wondering what part I'm missing. Is it because when the function finishes, all the timeouts it had started are cleaned up ?

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*max)+min);
}

function generateCircle(leftPos, topPos, zIndex) {

    $circle = $('<div class="cercleAnime"></div>');
    $('body').append($circle);
    var self = this;

    self.leftPos = leftPos;
    self.topPos = topPos;

    $circle.css({
        'left' : self.leftPos+'px',
        'top' : self.topPos+'px',
        'z-index' : zIndex
    });

    $circle.animate({'width' : '300px', 'height' : '300px'}, {
        duration : 5000,
        progress: function() {
            newLeft = self.leftPos - $(this).width()/2;
            newTop = self.topPos - $(this).height()/2;

            $(this).css({
                'left' : newLeft+'px',
                'top' : newTop+'px'
            })
        },
        done: function() {
            $(this).remove()
        }
    } );

}


function generateCircles(numberOfCircles, intervalBetweenCircles) {
    leftPos = getRandom(1,1000);
    topPos = getRandom(100,400);
    zIndex = 1000;
    timeoutTime = intervalBetweenCircles;

    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfCircles; i++) {
        zIndex--;
        setTimeout(function(){generateCircle(leftPos, topPos, zIndex)}, timeoutTime);
        timeoutTime += intervalBetweenCircles;
    }

}



$(function() {
    generateCircles(3, 2000);

    generateCircles(3, 2000);

    generateCircles(3, 2000);

    generateCircles(3, 2000);




});
```

Here's is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/BwyH7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are drawing circles with the *same characteristics* 4 times. (They nicely stack on top of each other and hide previous circles.)

This is because `leftPos` and `topPos` (etc) in `generateCircles` are *global variables* and are overwritten before the first circle even draws. Remember that the `setTimeout` callback will run "at some point in the future".

One solution is to use *local* variables such that they are *bound in the closure*:

```
var leftPos = getRandom(1,1000);
var topPos = getRandom(100,400);
// etc
```

(The closures in scope, i.e. the function passed to `setTimeout` still has access to these local variables .. that is what makes a closure a closure, after all.)